# Problems handling JS event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, events

I have a node Express app that uses some javascript in the app's view file.

I am trying to handle an element's onClick event...

This method works:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#dialog-continue', function () {
    alert('here')
});
```

This method does **not** work:

```js
$('#dialog-continue').on('click', function () {
    alert('here')
});
```

Can anyone tell me why the second method doesn't work?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: If you're adding `#dialog-continue` to the page dynamically you need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which is what the first example does.

Comment: Seconded @Andy, if the element is added to the page after the script is run you'll need to work around that with event delegation (or other).

Comment: The element is NOT added dynamically, unless maybe that is how Express handles loading views as a main page (the page the problem is on is not loaded as a partial using a <%- include partial_form.ejs %> syntax)!?!


But I took your suggestion as a hint and will rewrite the function as a "delegated event handler" - thanks!

Comment: Is your code running in the page in a location that is BEFORE the `#dialog-continue` element?  If so, that element doesn't yet exist when your script runs (it hasn't been parsed from the HTML by the browser yet) and the usual solution is to place the script at the end of the page so that all the HTML has been parsed when the script runs.

Comment: Nope - the element exists before the script.
I'll credit your first answer as the solution. Thanks for all your help )

Comment: You cannot mark a comment as an accepted answer. There is a deliberate distinction between comments and answers; this is one of them. Common protocol is to ask the commenter to post an answer so you can accept it.